# How to search effectively in the Django website

Tags: django, search, sphinx

I am trying to use the search functionality of the Django website effectively. Lets try the following search:

Say I would like get to get to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#id2) information on the Django website about **naming url patterns** and I would use `url` and `name=` as keywords in my search. (both keywords are present in the section I would like to find)

I tried the following searches but **none yielded any results**:

1. `url name=`
2. `url AND name=`
3. `"url" "name="`
4. `"url" AND "name="`

How can I find the [information I am looking for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#id2) with the keywords `url` and `name=`? I would prefer not to resort to grepping the docs locally.

Comment: Are you trying to provide that information to the end user? If so why? Are you trying to get that information for yourself? Then why not use a `find` tool?

Comment: Do you mean the `find` command in the shell, why would you use `find` instead of `grep`? Why I am asking is because I prefer to read the online docs in favour of raw reStructuredText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google to search a specific site with the `site:` search modifier. I got to your URL with this query:

`name= url site:djangoproject.com`